# How to create a splash screen for next.js v13 (app router) which isn't just cosmetic but calculates assets load time?

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, routes, app-router

### Objective

We have a content heavy webapp and to streamline the experience, we decided to introduce a preloader (splash-screen / loader) to our app.
Purpose of this component is to keep the user engaged until all the content (mostly images) loads.

---

### Issue

All the components of app router are server components by default.
How do I make sure that I am targeting all the dom elements and calculating their load times?

1. [this article suggests to create a HOC (react specific)](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-a-splash-screen-for-your-react-apps/)
2. [this article is using page router and using router methods (routeChangeStarted, routeChangeCompleted) to implement it](https://meje.dev/blog/building-a-nextjs-preloader-the-right-way)

---

next.js 13 (app router) doesn't expose router methods :(
how do I implement it?

---

### What, I've tried

I have made a component "preloader.js" that has a fixed positioning, a bit of markup and animation. In the rootLayout page, I am rendering this preloader component and setting a 6 sec timeout :( ( I know )

```
"use client";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import PreloaderNew from "./components/PreloaderNew";
{other irrelevent imports ...}


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  return (
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
...
        </head>

        <body className={`${trap.variable} chrome-no-scrollbar`}>
          <PreloaderNew loading={loading} />
...

            {children}
            <Footer />
        </body>
      </html>
  );
}
```

---

How can I check if the webpage is loaded? Most of the content is static on the homepage, so I am serving it directly.

---

Also, can I not have a loading.js file for the entire app?
[next.js loading documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/loading)

---

Please help me with this, suggestions, recommendations and links to resources is utmost welcomed. Thankyou.

Comment: Have you tried to add loading.js in the root folder of your app without any other "hacks"? It should work for the entire app as long as you don't have another one in a child route.

Comment: I did. It won't work. Even I am surprised !!

Comment: Might be because you have your root layout with "use client"

Comment: I did. It doesnt work, sadly
do you have a reference to any such working project

Comment: my root layout doesn't have 'use client' and also loading.js doesn't work